# MySQL query for WP bundles products

Tags: mysql, wordpress, string

I would like to extract the productnumbers and quantities from the following string:

```
 {"25628":{"quantity":"1","tax_included":"yes","thumbnail":"yes","title":"product 1","desc":""},"25629":{"quantity":"1","tax_included":"yes","thumbnail":"yes","title":"Product 2","desc":""}}
```

I would like to end up with (in this case 4 columns, but if more products are in the string more columns) with:

column_1_alias: product_1
value : 25628

column_2_alias: qty_pr_1
value: 1

column_3_alias: product_2
value : 25628

column_4_alias: qty_pr_2
value: 1

etc.

I tried with Substring but product title can differ so not all characters are always at the same position. Is there any way to split this string in usable data?

Any help would be very much appreciated..

Michel

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php - this will return the json to php readable format like object or array that you can easily manipulate. Please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: I tried to use this but I am not a programmer and it is too complex for me.. However I have opted for a different plugin that gives me an easier value to extract: 25628/1,25629/1. I would like to split this value in values before / and after / . So in this case 4 columns 25628 | 1 | 25629 | 1